# Need assistance with adb shell, on non rooted device

Tags: adb

I'm confuse with `adb shell` device login, I'm not able to go in root mode (# mode). I can only access $ mode from `adb shell` on any non rooted devices such as, Samsung galaxy Note, Galaxy 2 and Samsung galaxy Apollo (2.1), and as well not able to use "su -" command to be super user, and therefore restricted to directories such as `/data/data/com.myapp.exmple`.

But with root device can get root access with adb shell, and access them so my basic doubt is with non rooted devices can we get the root access with adb shell?

If not, I'm using Andrew Hoog's book "Synergy Android Forensics" which demonstrates adb shell can give you access to root (#mode) on non rooted devices, as well there are few examples on internet and forum which states so. take this video for example.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVJ7T2oC_Zs

Which is basically demonstrating how to unlock the security pattern lock with `adb shell`, which gets the root access (# mode) on non rooted device.

And if yes, what is the mistake I'm making? I install the latest JDK, then Android sdk in C:, then from `c:android-sdk/platform-tools/` directory tried to access the adb shell.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Cyanogenmod with Android 4.1.2 so this probably does not apply to stock roms. When I enter

```
adb root
```

the console returns

```
root access is disabled by system setting - enable in settings -> development options
```

in that menu you can *disable root access*, grant it for *apps only*, *adb only* and *apps and adb*. Select *apps and adb* and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `adb root` or `su-` wont work on non-rooted android mobiles.

You can Google on how to root your specific model, but beware that you may loose company warranty if you force root your phone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command for getting root access on Android:

```
adb root
```

I don't know if it works on any version of Android. The above command restarts the adb as root.

Comment: thanks...but it did not help. I got bellow message 
"adbd cannot run as root in production builds"
i tried using 2.1 and 4.0.4 ICS

Answer (score 0):

Tap your device version build number (at the bottom of the info page) 7 times for android 4.2. This will enable the developer's menu.